# How to shape the container?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make  different shape of a container in flutter.
For example, shaping the container to have a shape of octagonal, etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HI, could you share with us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend `CustomClipper` and define a custom path to be used with `ClipPath`. There are other pre-made clip widgets like `ClipOval` and `ClipRRect` (a rectangle with rounded corners). The below is an example of a star-shaped `Container`.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ClipPath(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        clipper: _MyClipper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.15);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.35, size.height * 0.4);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height * 0.4);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.25, size.height * 0.55);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.8);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.65);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.9, size.height * 0.8);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, size.height * 0.55);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.4);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.65, size.height * 0.4);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.15);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

[image]